# Problem with touch screen in Xubuntu

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have an ECline 1515 touch screen device running Xubuntu. I want to have 2 monitors, the main panel being the Ecline screen, plus another just for statistics. I need the touch screen as main, as it will be used 24/7.

Now, the touch screen splits in two if there's another screen connected; the display works fine, but its the touch, half of the screen's touch is one screen and the other half works for the other screen. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muXe8.jpg)